# How do I save the contents of ellipsis in R to be used in deeply nested function calls?

Tags: r, ellipsis, nested-function

I'm trying to write a function that iterates through all the files in the immediate sub-directories of a directory, and then runs a custom-written function to extract features from the text of the files:

```
load.samples <- function(path = ".", ...) {
  dirs <- dir(path, full.names = TRUE)[file.info(dir(path, full.names = TRUE))$isdir]
  lapply(dirs, function(p) {
    lapply(dir(p, full.names = TRUE), function(f) {
      text <- readChar(f, file.info(f)$size)
      extractFeatures(text, ...) #I want this call to pass along the extra parameters to load.samples
    })
  })
}
```

I'm trying to have any additional arguments passed to the `load.samples` function be carried through to the `extractFeatures` function.  However, the code above obviously doesn't work, because instead of being directly called, the call to `extractFeatures` is wrapped inside two nested functions that are called via two nested calls to `lapply`, and I get an unused argument error whenever I try to pass any extra parameters to `load.samples`.

What is the simplest way to save the value of the ellipses to be used in such nested functions?

Comment: How exactly are you calling this function? And why is the failure so obvious? Something like this seems to work fine: `mycall<-function(a,b, ...) paste(a,b,...); f<-function(a,b, ...) { sapply(a, function(a) { sapply(b, function(b) {mycall(a,b,...)}) }) }; f(1:3, 3:4, "Hi")`

Comment: Based on janos's answer, it looks like how I thought my code was "obviously wrong" was, well, obviously wrong!

This was the call I was using (and now works thanks to janos): `load.samples(path = "~/projects/linguist/samples", ncol = 10)`, where `ncol` is intended to be passed to the `extractFeatures` function.

Comment: There are several packages that contain an `extractFeatures` function. (`sdef`, `pathClass`, `NMF`, `imageHTS`).  For reproducibility, please can you specify which one you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first line to this:

```
load.samples <- function(..., path = ".") {
```

The trick is that `...` should come after the regular parameters, but *before* the named parameters.

Comment: I guess it was hard to tell if the intention was to have `path` be the first positional value with a default value, or have it be an` optional named parameter. In theory, the first syntax should have worked if you wanted `path` to be the first positional parameter with a default value.